# Fragen ohne eigene Bemühungen

Tags: discussion

Ich bin in den letzten Tagen über Fragen wie [What's the difference between "reinigen", "sauber machen" and "säubern"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/41578/whats-the-difference-between-reinigen-sauber-machen-and-s%c3%a4ubern) und [When to use “Bedürfnis” and “Bedarf”?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/41539/when-to-use-bed%c3%bcrfnis-and-bedarf) und [What are the main meanings of "Bescheid"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/41474/what-are-the-main-meanings-of-bescheid) gestossen --- alles Fragen, wo der Fragesteller keine Eigeninitiative gezeigt hat, die Unterschiede herauszufinden.

Ist sowas noch on-topic? Ich hab jeweils für Schließen und ins Wörterbuch gucken gestimmt, aber manche dieser Fragen sind noch offen, also sehen das einige hier anders. Was sind Eure Meinungen zu solchen Fragen?

Ich habe nichts gegen Fragen nach Unterschieden zwischen ähnlichen Wörtern. Mich stört nur das Fragen ohne erkennbare eigene Bemühung, den Unterschied herauszufinden und ohne Kontext.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ich denke, uns allen sind diese Fragen der letzten Tage aufgefallen, die von einem neuen Mitglied vermehrt gestellt werden. Er oder sie tut sich noch ein wenig schwer mit unseren Anforderungen, ist aber sehr kooperativ und zeigt eine deutliche Tendenz zur Besserung.

Es wäre in diesem Fall schade, wenn dieses Mitglied in einen "Frage-Bann" rutschte, denn ich glaube er/sie hat ein ehrliches Interesse an der deutschen Sprache und gibt sich Mühe, die Fragen zu verbessern, das ist aber schwierig, weil er/sie weder Deutsch noch Englisch gut kann.

Solche Fragen kommen aber auch von anderen und seit Jahren immer wieder, was uns zeigt, dass es ein allgemeines Problem ist, wie ein Anfänger nur mit einem Wörterbuch herausfindet, welche der angebotenen Varianten nun die richtige ist.

Ich meine, dass wir in solchen Fällen durchaus helfen können und auch sollten. Je mehr wir über die Probleme des Einzelnen wissen, also je mehr uns über die Wörterbuch-Recherche gesagt wurde, und je besser uns der gewünschte Kontext genannt wurde, desto besser können wir helfen. Wenn beides fehlt, dann geht es aber beim besten Willen nicht. Wenn dann zudem noch unsere Nachfragen in Kommentaren ignoriert werden, dann ist es angebracht die Frage `[on hold]` zu setzen.

Ich würde aber den Schließgrund *unclear* bevorzugen, denn das ist es letztlich: unklar, wo das Problem liegt. Oder wir geben einen eigenen Schließgrund an, z.B. "missing context". Den Grund *off topic* sollten wir auf solche Fälle beschränken, in denen es wirklich nur einen unzweifelhaften Wörterbucheintrag gibt.

Wir sollten dabei aber beachten, dass es keinen guten Eindruck macht, wenn wir alle diese Fragen über einen Kamm scheren und schon gar nicht wenn wir nur Fragen einzelner Benutzer herauspicken, während ähnliche Fragen anderer Benutzer erlaubt sind.

Wenn ein Problem von allgemeinem Interesse ist, kann man schon auch mal eine solche Frage "retten", in dem man sie durch ein Edit präzisiert. Damit ist letztlich allen geholfen.

Comment: Bevor ich eine solche Frage mit "kuck doch ins Wörterbuch"  abkanzle, schau' ich, wenn ich ein bißchen Zeit habe, selber rein - Sehr oft ist es so, dass Online-Wörterbücher nicht wirklich erklären, welche Bedeutung gerade hier passt oder eine bestimmte Wendung dort gar nicht oder mißverständlich vorkommt. In solchen Fällen spare ich mir das Flaggen. Trotzdem wäre es schön, wenn der Fragesteller wenigstens erwähnte, was er gefunden hat und daran nicht versteht.

Comment: Im Prinzip stimme ich dieser Antwort zu. Ich bin sehr für eine großzügige Interpretation von Geduld mit Neulingen, anerkennen von Bemühungen und Lernwille. Der konkrete Fall scheint mir aber etwas resistent zu sein. Kein Informed badge, 0 accepts, jede neue Frage im alten Stil, trotz all der Kommentare. Ich sage ausdrücklich nicht, dass auch nur eine dieser Fragen grundsätzlich keine Berechtigung hätte (kann sein/kann nicht sein…). Ich sage aber, dass wir in der Kommunikation versagen. "Einen Benutzer herauspicken" ist etwas anderes als durch die Frequenz aufmerksam geworden zu sein.

Comment: @LangLangC: die haben es schwer, weil sie weder [Deutsch noch Englisch](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/41575/how-to-use-erg%c3%a4nzend-and-zus%c3%a4tzlich-in-sentences#comment103193_41575) gut können. Wir sollten vielleicht ein wenig nachsichtig sein, aber im Prinzip hast Du schon recht. Trotzdem müssen wir immer jeden Post einzeln und vom Autor losgelöst betrachten (das ist ein grundlegendes SE-Prinzip).